# What's the definition of a microlocal sheaf?

Tags: sheaf-theory, derived-categories, derived-algebraic-geometry, perverse-sheaves, micro-local-analysis

I'm slowly becoming familiar with what microsupport of a sheaf is, but none of the references I've seen give a definition of what a microlocal sheaf should be in general.

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.07050) paper of Bezrukavnikov and Kapranov, they define microlocal sheaves on nodal curves as perverse sheaves on the normalization along with some extra information at the points of self-intersection.  They say, as one would expect, that this is the simplest case, but they don't elaborate or give an indication as to what the more general definition should be.

Comment: This paper of Nadler and Shende is relevant: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.10154.pdf . Jin and Treumann is also helpful: https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04291